Getting a JWT from Amplify Auth/Cogntio in React to send to my backend for verification
I have been struggling getting and agreeable token format to be able to verify it on my backend (Python Flask).
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import { fetchAuthSession } from 'aws-amplify/auth';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
import awsconfig from "../../aws-exports.js";

These are the amplify related packages I'm using
This is what my Authenticator implementation looks like.
    <Authenticator
    signUpAttributes={[
      'name'
    ]}>
      {({ user }) => {
        if (user && !loginInitiated) {
          setLoginInitiated(true);
          fetchAuthSession().then((session) => {
            handleLogin(session)
            console.log(loginInitiated);
          });
        }
      }}
    </Authenticator>

And what my request to the backend looks like:
      const response = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/login`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ token: session.tokens.idToken }),
        credentials: 'include',
      });

I am trying to obtain the JWT from the 'session' object from fetchAuthSession().
I have tried using session.tokens.idToken and session.tokens.accessToken. Maybe I am confused about the approach to this- but shouldn't I be passing a JWT to my backend instead of this?
{
  "token": {
    "payload": {
      "sub": "REDACTED",
      "email_verified": true,
      "iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_REDACTED",
      "cognito:username": "REDACTED",
      "origin_jti": "REDACTED",
      "aud": "REDACTED",
      "event_id": "REDACTED",
      "token_use": "id",
      "auth_time": 1726174013,
      "name": "My Name",
      "exp": 1726244464,
      "iat": 1726240864,
      "jti": "REDACTED",
      "email": "REDACTED"
    }
  }
}

This is the documentation I have been referring to try and get the token from fetchAuthSession().
Thanks a ton
I have tried sending the current payload I am getting to my flask backend to verify it against the public key obtained from my user pool token signing URL. I believe I just need to change what type of token I am getting from the frontend but it has not been clear how from amplify docs.
